# Get web part Id with javascript client OM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Do you know how to get the current web part Id with the javascript client OM  API ?

Or an idea for a work-around ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your Web Part will have an element attribute called `webpartid` so you can use this to select all Web Parts, like this (jQuery):

```
$('[webpartid]');
```

To select your own specific Web Part you could add something specific in the markup you can use to select it, for example an empty/hidden element with a specific class, like `<span class="my-hack"></span>`, then your Web Part can be selected like this (jQuery):

```
$('[webpartid]:has(.my-hack)');
 // or
$('.my-hack');
// or
$('.my-hack').closest('[webpartid]');
```

Comment: thx ! Do you know a way to access a specific instance (in the case where there are more than one instances of this web part in a page) ?

Comment: That is what the .my-hack is for, something within the markup that tells you it is your Web Part. You could also use the Title, but this is dangerous as the title can be removed (Chrome Frame Type). In theory: `$('[webpartid]:has(.my-hack)').each(function(){ var $myWP = $(this); ... });`

Comment: it didn't worked for me, I had to get it with : $('.someClass').parents('.ms-WPBody').attr('webpartid');

Comment: The one I used with `.closest` should work, it reads as > "recursive parent of your element (.my-hack) with attribute 'webpartid' defined"

Comment: So this will not work if you have an instance of the same webpart with a hidden .my-hack in it. Example: think of an image slider, but you want to get image list from the weppart property. On $().ready() if you try to find $('.my-hack').closest('[webpartid]'); it will always bring back the first webpart and not the webpart where the script was called from. Any solutions?

Comment: @dotsa I might be wrong, but isn't your question the same as the first comment by dino? If so look at my answer in the second comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can select it by position or title and then retrieve the id with JSOM, here is an example based on position:

```
function GetWPInfo()
{
    var currentCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var pageFile = currentCtx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
    var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
    currentCtx.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(Id)');
    currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        if (webPartDefs.get_count()) {
                var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(1);
                alert(webPartDef.get_id());
        }
        else {
            console.log("No web parts found.");
        }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```