# How to get WebPart on current page by name/ID with javascript?

Tags: 2010, web-part, client-object-model

I have a page with some webparts on it, I want to get specific one (by name or ID) using client javascript.
I try this code

```
var ctx=SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var site = ctx.get_site();
var theURL = window.location.pathname;
var oFile = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(theURL);
var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(collWebPart);
ctx.executeQueryAsync();
```

How to get webpart by name or id after i get a collection?
Maybe there is a easier way to do it?

Comment: What is the intent of getting the webpart id? What do you want the code to do? This may help define he path needed to accomplish the goal.

Comment: We have a webpart that displays a list. 
I want to get information from this web part, e.g. e-mails.

Comment: If you are using client object model you should be able to use jQuery just as well. It may be easier!

Comment: It has the answer i tested by id
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx

Comment: This is a duplicate of:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46474/get-web-part-id-with-javascript-client-om

Marking as duplicate.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question asks how to get the ID. This question asks how to get the WebPart from the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you execute the example you have above, you can (for example) get the title of all web parts on the page by executing this:

```
var i = collWebPart.get_count()
for (var j=0;j<i;j++)
{ 
    var webPart = collWebPart.get_item(j).get_webPart()
    ctx.load(webPart);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();

    webPart.get_title();
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185010.aspx

However, based on your comment above, it sounds like you might be looking for a value from a field from a listitem displayed in the list displayed by this webpart. If that is the case, you might want to try a more direct approach by getting the list, and then the list item, rather than getting the webpart.